# Using linux command "sort -f | uniq -i" together for ignoring case

Tags: linux, sorting, awk, gawk, uniq

I am trying to find unique and duplicate data in a list of data with two columns.  I really just want to compare the data in column 1.

The data might look like this (separated by a tab):

```
What are you doing?     Che cosa stai facendo?
WHAT ARE YOU DOING?     Che diavolo stai facendo?
what are you doing?     Qual è il tuo problema amico?
```

So I have been playing around with the following:

1. Sorting without ignoring case **(just "sort", no -f option)** gives me less duplicates

   gawk '{ FS = "\t" ; print $1 }' EN-IT_Corpus.txt | **sort**    | uniq -i -D > dupes
2. Sorting with ignoring case **("sort -f")** gives me more duplicates

   gawk '{ FS = "\t" ; print $1 }' EN-IT_Corpus.txt | **sort -f** | uniq -i -D > dupes

Am I right to think that #2 is more accurate if I want to find duplicates ignoring case, because it sorts it ignoring case first and then finds duplicates based on the sorted data?

As far as I know I can't combine the sort and unique commands because sort doesn't have an option for displaying duplicates.

Thanks, 
Steve

Comment: What is the output you want from your sample data?

Answer (score 34):

You might keep it simple:

```
sort -uf
#where sort -u = the unique findings
#      sort -f = insensitive case
```

Comment: I'm surprised no one thought of this in 5 years ;)

Answer (score 9):

I think the key is to preprocess the data:

```
file="EN-IT_Corpus.txt"
dups="dupes.$$"
sed 's/        .*//' $file | sort -f | uniq -i -D > $dups
fgrep -i -f $dups $file
```

The `sed` command generates just the English words; these are sorted case-insensitively, and then run through `uniq` case-insensitively, only printing duplicated entries.  Then process the data file again, looking for those duplicated keys with `fgrep` or `grep -F`, specifying the patterns to look for in the file `-f $dups`.  Obviously (I hope) the big white space in the `sed` command is a tab; you may be able to write `\t` depending on your shell and `sed` and so on.

In fact, with GNU `grep`, you can do:

```
sed 's/        .*//' $file |
sort -f |
uniq -i -D |
fgrep -i -f - $file
```

And if the number of duplicates is really big, you can squeeze them down with:

```
sed 's/        .*//' $file |
sort -f |
uniq -i -D |
sort -f -u |
fgrep -i -f - $file
```

Given the input data:

```
What a surprise?        Vous etes surpris?
What are you doing?        Che cosa stai facendo?
WHAT ARE YOU DOING?        Che diavolo stai facendo?
Provacation         Provacatore
what are you doing?        Qual è il tuo problema amico?
Ambiguous        Ambiguere
```

the output from all of these is:

```
What are you doing?        Che cosa stai facendo?
WHAT ARE YOU DOING?        Che diavolo stai facendo?
what are you doing?        Qual è il tuo problema amico?
```

Answer (score 5):

or this:

unique:

```
awk '!arr[tolower($1)]++'  inputfile > unique.txt
```

duplicates

```
awk '{arr[tolower($1)]++; next} 
END{for (i in arr {if(arr[i]>1){print i, "count:", arr[i]}} }' inputfile > dup.txt
```